# "Values" object has no attribute "save"

Tags: python, save, init, self

I am trying to work with the code below. However it is a written code by my professor and also in python2 (I already made quite some changes). I use python 3.8.5.

When I try to run the code it yield me the Attribute Error below. Trying to adapt it by changing it the syntax or shorten up to save did not work and I also do not came across any reference of **save** in the web.

```py
def __init__(self, options):

        self.save_each = options.save_each

        self.origin_dir = "NET-%s-%s-%s"%(options.currency, options.heuristic, options.epoch)
        if options.save_each is not None:
            self.origin_dir += "_%s"%options.save_each
```

```
File "comp-1-network_centrality.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.save_each = options.save_each
AttributeError: 'Values' object has no attribute 'save_each'
```

Looking forward to help.

Comment: Please update your question with actual example code and error traceback. What you have posted is not consistent. Your code says: `self.save_each = options.save_each`, but the traceback says: `self.save = options.save`

Comment: Thanks, I updated it, I just tried 100 things out. But the problem is still not solved.

Comment: You are passing the `options` argument as a `None`.

Comment: more of the surrounding code may be necessary for context